# How to grab corresponding value from the results generated from a foreach statement

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am creating a cart page 
Package used - Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

To add quantity I am using Ajax calls,
For single product I can update the quantity and decrease it, everything's perfect. The problem 
arises when I try to add another item to the cart and try updating its quantity.

I think issue is with my way of grabbing the rowID. Since am using foreach and calling the class of it I am getting only the first 
id.

I am not sure how do I grab the id's differently. I am not pasting all the cart code as it would be more longer

Here is my code,

> Blade:

```
@foreach (Cart::Content() as $cartcontent)
<footer class="content">
                <input type="hidden" class="rowID" name="" value="{{$cartcontent->rowId}}">
                <span class="qt-minus">-</span>
                <span class="qt">{{$cartcontent->qty}} </span>
                <span class="qt-plus">+</span>
                <h2 class="full-price">
                    {{$cartcontent->model->presentPrice() * $cartcontent->qty}}
                </h2>

                <h2 class="price">
                    {{$cartcontent->model->presentPrice()}}
                </h2>
            </footer>
<br>@endforeach
```

In the html source code the above rowID is different

> js

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    function cartLogic(){
      // var rowID = $('#rowID').val();
      var rowID =  $('.rowID').val();
    var quantity = $('.qt').text();
    console.log(rowID);
    console.log(quantity);
    $.ajax({
                url: 'cart/'+ rowID,
                // url: 'cart/'+ $('#rowID').val(),
                type: 'PATCH',
                data: {  "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                quantity : quantity,
                 _method: "PATCH"},
                success: function(res) {
console.log(res);
// window.location.reload();
                }
        });
    }

  $(".qt-plus").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children(".qt").html(parseInt($(this).parent().children(".qt").html()) + 1);
    //  console.log('working');
       cartLogic();

  });
```

> Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // return $request->all();
        // dd(Cart::content());
        $quantity = $request->quantity;
        Cart::update($id, $quantity); // Will update the quantity

    }
```

> Route

```
Route::patch('cart/{id}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
```

When I view the console.log(rowID); I only get the first products id. 
What should be done to get the corresponding ID

Any help should be much appreciated

Comment: `.val()` used in read mode only gets the value from the first element - as is explicitly stated in the documentation. If you want the values from all elements, then you have to _loop over_ all elements, and get the value for each of them individually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @misorude. I am currently rewriting the code.

Comment: (And you probably want to get the text content from the `.qt` elements individually as well. `.text()` behaves differently than `.val()`, and _combines_ the text content of all elements - but that is probably not what you want here either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what you can do on client side:

```
function cartLogic(rowID){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cart/'+ rowID,
        type: 'PATCH',
        data: { 
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            _method: "PATCH"
        },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
}

$(".qt-plus").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children(".qt").html(parseInt($(this).parent().children(".qt").html()) + 1);
    // Here you get ID of a cart record
    var rowID = $(this).parent().find('.rowID').val();

    cartLogic(rowID);
});
```

Note that I removed `quantity` from ajax-query. If you need it - you can add it as second parameter to `cartLogic`. But be careful that someone can modify js-script and pass a `10000000000` value as quantity or `-42`. What will you do then?) So, it is safer to pass just the id of the cart record to server and increase quantity by 1 on server.

On server side you should update your record with query like:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET quantity = quantity + 1 WHERE rowID = id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, The above solution solved the issue. I was struggling for past 8 hrs to solve it. :)